# Check inArray from a php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

**PHP:**

```
$ports = $Db->query('SELECT port FROM servers');
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#port").on('keyup', function(){
    var port = $("#port").val();
    var portlist = <?php print(json_encode($ports)); ?>;

    if(jQuery.inArray(port, portlist[port])!==-1)
    {
        $("#result").removeClass("label-success");
        $("#result").removeClass("label-warning");
        $("#result").addClass("label label-danger");
        $("#result").html("Port belegt!");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#result").removeClass("label-danger");
        $("#result").removeClass("label-warning");
        $("#result").addClass("label label-success");
        $("#result").html("Port Frei!");
    }



})
```

Why is this not working?

The array contains `1234` and `7777`.
So if I type `7777` into the html input field (`#port`) it should do the first action (if true)

But it always goes into the else action.

Comment: Change ```if(jQuery.inArray(port, portlist[port])!==-1)``` to ```if(jQuery.inArray(port, portlist)!==-1)```. Otherwise you'd need to check if portlist[port] exists and that's not inArray.

Comment: Hmm okay. But then the variable portlist only contains `[object Object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to cast integers in array to string by quoting and remove [port]
here is a working example of your code
http://jsfiddle.net/4X68y/

```
 var portlist = ["1234","777"];

    if(jQuery.inArray(port, portlist)!==-1)
```

Comment: So the values from php are strings, right?
Without the mysql query (`var portlist = ["1234","777"];`), it works..

Comment: well thats my guess. check the source code if php outputs `[1234,7777]` or `["1234","7777"]`. if its the first, you can always typecast integer values with (string)$intval

Comment: Thats the output from php (`print_r`): `Array ( [0] => Array ( [port] => 7777 ) [1] => Array ( [port] => 1234 ) )`

Comment: ports seem to be integer. just iterate the array and parse them to string. `foreach($ports as $key=>$port) { $ports[$key] = (string)$port; }`

Comment: No change. I get the same result :(

Comment: then try this: `foreach($ports as $port) { $portArr[] = $port['port'];  }; $portJson = '["' . implode('","',$portArr) . '"]';`

Comment: YES! You made it bro! :D I did not think that it is so tricky :|

Answer (score 0):

jQuery inArray accepts array as second parameter - not specific key.

Try this:

```
$("#port").on('keyup', function(){
var port = $(this).val();
var portlist = <?php print(json_encode($ports)); ?>;

if(jQuery.inArray(port, portlist)!==-1)
{
    $("#result").removeClass("label-success");
    $("#result").removeClass("label-warning");
    $("#result").addClass("label label-danger");
    $("#result").html("Port belegt!");
}
else
{
    $("#result").removeClass("label-danger");
    $("#result").removeClass("label-warning");
    $("#result").addClass("label label-success");
    $("#result").html("Port Frei!");
}
```

})

--EDIT--

The following works for me (if the portlist is array not json object. If it isnt maybe it's a good idea to just loop the results and create the array old fashioned way like below)

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$q = $db->query("SELECT port FROM ports");
$ports = array();
while($$row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $ports[] = $row['port'];
        } 
?>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
$("#port").on('keyup', function(){
var port = parseInt($(this).val());
var portlist = <?php print(json_encode($ports)); ?>;

if(jQuery.inArray(port, portlist)===-1)
{
    $("#result").removeClass("label-success");
    $("#result").removeClass("label-warning");
    $("#result").addClass("label label-danger");
    $("#result").html("Port belegt!");
}
else
{
    $("#result").removeClass("label-danger");
    $("#result").removeClass("label-warning");
    $("#result").addClass("label label-success");
    $("#result").html("Port Frei!");
}
})
```

Comment: but without the specified key, I only get `[object Object]` :S

Comment: Could you please past what have you got in portlist variable after printing json_encode($ports)?

Comment: Sure. I get `[{"port":7777},{"port":1234}] `

Comment: As i thought - u're getting it's parsed as json object that's why you're getting back object - pretty obvious right? Look my edit for answer :) Best regards.

Comment: I'm getting confused :S. Your example does not use the php array, right?

Comment: Edit the code so you could just copy-paste it :) check it out.